# Открытие ссылки

Tags: php

С помощью `preg_match` произвожу парсинг ссылки с сайта, далее пытаюсь перейти по этой ссылке вот так

```
header('location: '.$confirmLink);
```

но тут внезапно :) в адресной строке появляется вместо `& => &amp%3b` и та страница, которая нужна не открывается...

Как быть? Пробовал заменять `preg_replace` `&amp%3b` на это `&`, но тоже самое происходит. ((

Comment: Значит такая ссылка кривая изначально 

>&amp%3b 

это не тоже самое что и 

> &

Comment: если эту ссылку запихнуть в <a href=''> то при клике норм переходит(без &amp%3b), а так автоматом открывать не хочет

Answer (score 1):

[urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: уже пробовал, не помогло(

Comment: содержимое $confirmLink в студию